# how do i make the "box-shadow" to the whole div

Tags: html, css

I want to display image on the left and text next to it, but I want the box shadow after the image, how to do it?

## HTML

```
<div class="image_carousel">
<img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-        vp16kljkPwg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAKg/Ypz8rdBRFjQ/photo.jpg?sz=200"  alt=""/>
<p>
hello there the angel
</p>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.image_carousel {
  margin-top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;
}
.image_carousel img{
  float:left;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need this:

```css
.image_carousel {
  margin-top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;
}
.image_carousel img{
  float:left;
  width: 60px;
 }
 
 .image_carousel p{
  float:left;
 }
 
 .clear {
   clear: both;
 }
```

```html
<div class="image_carousel">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFYTl.jpg?s=328&g=1"  alt=""/>
<p>
hello there the angel
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain more or describe what you exactly want with an image? I get this with your question, but look like it's not your goal.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean of `but I want the box shadow after the image` @yankiepalans

Comment: i want box shadow to the whole image and text both. ( a box - inside there is image and text) 
Image on the left and text next to it

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding a `div` as wrapper for your text and instead applying `box-shadow` to `image_carousel` apply to the elements inside.

HTML:

```
<div class="image_carousel">
<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-NN2h0whe9D4/Tc4y4i54GAI/AAAAAAAAGt0/ZrKTEZ30wAQ/s1600/windows_7_logo_from_wallpaper.png"  alt=""/>
<div class="content">
<p>
hello there the angel
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image_carousel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.image_carousel .content{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;
}
.image_carousel img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;
 }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8dj4sf12/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap everything in a div, which has a box-shadow.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-caroussel>
  etc etc..
</div>
```

Then do the box-shadow on the container:

```
.container { box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #000; }
```

Hope this helps :)